# how to pass value from activity to tabactivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

i have a activity,i want to pass  value from activity  to tabactivity so that to change the tab of tabactivity,mu code: activity:

```
           intent.putExtra("tabNumber", "2");
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setClass(context, TabSubActivities.class);
```

the follow code in the tabActivity:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getParent().getIntent().getExtras();
    //Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String tabNumber = bundle.getString("tabNumber");
        if (tabNumber != null && !tabNumber.equals(""))
        {
             int No= Integer.getInteger(tabNumber);
             Log.i("cc","aa");
            // ((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(No);
        }
        else
        {
             Log.i("cc","bb");
            // ((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    }
    else
        {
            Log.i("cc","cc");
            //((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);
          }
```

but i cannot get the Log information,and give me mistake,how to form activity to change tabactivity tab,for example: tabactivity default show tab(0),i want to show tab(1),but i want   the activity  not belongs to  tavactivty to change the tavactivty tab

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intent Filters for that purpose.
Just broadcast your event in your activity 
and handle it in your tabActivity.

Answer (score 0):

int No= Integer.getInteger(tabNumber) this line is mistake,i used  int No= Integer.parseInt(tabNumber);